# Filtering array in a foreach using PHP

Tags: php

I want to filter my array with my another array name value! Here it will be 17, 18

```
$myarray = Array
 (
   [0] = Array
    (
        [name] = 17
    )

    [1] = Array
    (
        [name] = 18
    )

)

$filterBy = $myarray; 

$new = array_filter($result, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
return ($var['name'] == $filterBy);
});

print_r($new);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: not sure what you mean by filter. an expected result would be nice. you could be looking for ```array_merge()```

Comment: `$filterBy` is the entire `$myArray` array. Why are you comparing it to the `name` of an element of `$result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you really want:

```
$filterBy = array_column($myarray, 'name');
$new = array_filter($result, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return in_array($var['name'], $filterBy);
});
```

This filters `$result` by looking for elements whose names are also names in `$myarray`.

You can make it more efficient by turning the names into keys of an associative array:

```
$filterBy = array_flip(array_column($myarray, 'name'));
$new = array_filter($result, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return isset($filterBy[$var['name']]);
});
```